# Date property in alertLocalizationArgs

Tags: swift, date, cloudkit

I'm working with CKSubscription. I set alertLocalizationArgs array for a date property. When I would like to get the date from alertLocalizationArgs, I get 6.71963003895015E8. I don't know what is that. It cannot be a double beacsue the string contains "E". Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the argument actually the string "6.71963003895015E8", or is that how it's being displayed? If it's a string you'll have to create a `NumberFormatter` and set its `numberStyle`  to `.scientific`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`6.71963003895015E8` is scientific notation and is the same as `671963003.895015`

And

```
Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 671963003.895015)
```

is today, April 18, 2022.